# How to get the content item defined as the default view of a folder in Plone?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Plone 4 has the option to define a content item as the default view of a folder ([Example here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/managing-content/folderdisplaymenu.png)). But, how do I get this information programmatically? I tried the `getLayout()` method but it doesn't contain this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the intended method was [`getDefaultPage()`](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI/blob/master/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/interfaces.py#L25).